# Find an axial line on rotated coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

Asuming x and y are uniformly distributed, as in the code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rearrr)
#> Warning: package 'rearrr' was built under R version 4.3.2
x <- runif(2000, min = 0, max = 1)
y <- runif(2000, min = -0.4, max = 0.4)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
dfr <- rotate_2d(df, -30, origin = c(0.5, 0), x_col = "x", y_col = "y")
ggplot(dfr) + geom_point(aes(x, y)) + geom_smooth(aes(x, y), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

We can easily do a linear regression to approximate the axial line of the points:

[image]

But after we rotate all the points by a certain degree around the central point,linear regression won't do the trick:

```r
ggplot(dfr) + geom_point(aes(x_rotated, y_rotated)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x_rotated, y_rotated), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is there a approach to find the rotation angle (and probably the central point) and correctly plot the axial line as shown in red?

[image]

Comment: I don't see how a linear regression estimates the axial line of the points (assuming this is even a well-defined concept, which it isn't in many cases). It does in the special case of a rectangular bivariate uniform distribution where the x axis support is larger than the y axis support, but it is not, in general, a great method to use. If you flipped the x and y axes, a linear regression would be orthogonal to the correct line. Is your goal to find a method of finding such a line (where it exists?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same idea as the approach by @SamR but slightly different as I use a separate data frame for the fitted values and add the confidence band using a `geom_polygon` as after rotating the lower and upper bound no longer share the same x coordinate (and hence a `geom_ribbon` will no longer work):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rearrr)

set.seed(123)

degree <- -30
n <- 200

x <- runif(2000, min = 0, max = 1)
y <- runif(2000, min = -0.4, max = 0.4)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
dfr <- rotate_2d(df, degree, origin = c(0.5, 0), x_col = "x", y_col = "y")

mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

df_fit <- data.frame(
  x = seq(0, 1, length.out = n)
)

df_fit[c("y", "ymin", "ymax")] <-
  predict(mod, newdata = df_fit, interval = "confidence")

cols <- c("y", "ymin", "ymax")
dfr_fit <- lapply(cols, \(y) {
  dfr <- rotate_2d(df_fit, degree,
    origin = c(0.5, 0),
    x_col = "x", y_col = y
  )
  dfr <- dfr[c("x_rotated", paste0(y, "_rotated"))]
  names(dfr) <- c("x_rotated", "y_rotated")
  dfr
})

dfr_ribbon <- rbind(
  dfr_fit[[2]],
  dfr_fit[[3]][rev(seq(n)), ]
)

ggplot(dfr, aes(x_rotated, y_rotated)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .4, size = .5) +
  geom_polygon(data = dfr_ribbon, fill = "red", alpha = .4) +
  geom_line(data = dfr_fit[[1]], color = "#3366FF", linewidth = 1)
```

[image]